# Map a function with multiple arguments over an ee.ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm building a Python function for Google Earth Engine that takes two arguments: `image` is an input ee.Image and `fields` is an input ee.FeatureCollection. The function uses these two arguments to return a masked image, as shown below:

```
def mask_image(image, fields):
    return image.clipToCollection(fields)
```

Now I need to map this function over an ee.ImageCollection. However, the `.map()` method only takes functions with a single argument. How can I wrap `mask_image` in a new function that is mappable to an entire ee.ImageCollection?

Comment: Hi, not testing this, but your function seems like a mask_collection(imagecollection, featurecollection) parameters function, in which you can put a mask_image(image) function to be mapped over the imagecollection with the featurecolection values defined in the upper call

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. The algorithm you specify in `map()` must take exactly one argument.

If you want that exact signature of your `mask_image` function, this is one option:

```
def mask_image(image, fields):
    return image.clipToCollection(fields)


masked = collection.map(lambda image: mask_image(image, fields))
```